# Node.js Stream - Buffer to String gives [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am would like to be able to filter the output. However, I am having a issue converting from buffer to string. `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.toString()));` keeps giving me `[object Object]` which I can not use. How can I convert the buffer to string so I can filter out the contents to stdout?

```
//inject 'bower and javascript' files or just 'javascript' files
function injectStream(sourceStream, filesStream) {
    sourceStream
        .pipe(injector(filesStream, { ignorePath: 'app', addRootSlash: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(INDEX_PATH_PARENT))
        .pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, next) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.toString()));
            this.push(obj.contents);
            next();
    })).pipe(process.stdout)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`through2.obj` makes an object stream (or a stream in object mode). Through an object stream objects flow, not buffers. What you get is not a buffer, but an object `obj`. That is why its `toString` method gives `[object Object]`. Perhaps what you are looking for is in `obj.contents`?

Comment: Strangely enough `console.log(obj.contents)` gives me `<Buffer 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 3e 0a 09 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0a 09 09 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 22 75 74 66 2d 38 22 20 2f 3e ...>`

Comment: And calling `toString` on the buffer?

Comment: `console.log(obj.contents.toString());` works. However, it gives me the whole contents at once. I was hoping for line by line since I thought it was iterating with `next()`.

Comment: You should be aware of some [issues](http://r.va.gg/2014/06/why-i-dont-use-nodes-core-stream-module.html) with node's streams. There's also substack's [stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) for an introduction.

Comment: How come I was not able to see the object properties with `console.log(obj)`? Even with json.stringify I couldn't.  Made it hard to trouble shoot.

Comment: It might be that there is a ditinction between the objects own properties and those that it inherits from its prototype. Check out `obj.prototype` or `obj.__proto__`